# Stupid question #1 "would have" or "would"

Tags: would, would-have-been

I have this sentence: "Sometimes you can find friendship where you would have never thought **you would have**"

Why is the last part of the sentence "you would have" and not just "you would". Please guys help me out..

I got this from non-native speaker, and i got curious because it sounds weird to me.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I got this from non-native speaker on instagam, it really threw me off myself. There was no additional context behind it was just two people in a photo and this sentence. Sorry i'm non-native myself and i got curious.

Comment: not a stupid question at all imo!  My understanding is that "would have" is considered more proper in this case.

Comment: The base sentence here is  'Sometimes you can find friendship where you would never  have thought you would have found friendship' which I'd say mismatches modals. But 'Sometimes you may find friendship where you would never  have thought you could have found friendship' reduces to 'Sometimes you may find friendship where you would never  have thought you could' while 'Sometimes you may find friendship where you would never  have thought you could have done' may be reduced to 'Sometimes you may find friendship where you would never  have thought you could have'. But I'd say it sounds odd.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but are these 3 sentences have the same meaning: "Sometimes you may find friendship where you would never have thought you could have done", "Sometimes you may find friendship where you would never have thought you could have", "Sometimes you may find friendship where you would never have thought you could"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does sound awkward, doesn't it? I recommend deleting that clause entirely:
... where you would have never thought. Or replace *thought* with *expected*.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please check out our help page on [how to write a good answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) When you get a little more rep you will be able to comment.

Comment: Hello, Libby. Essentially, this is a workaround, very sensible and probably the best solution, but it doesn't directly address OP's question.